# Answer with white transparent overlay

Tags: support, design

According to the question [If up-vote after down-vote, user is getting rewarded for useless answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169301/if-up-vote-after-down-vote-user-is-getting-rewarded-for-useless-answer) and the related question on SO.

Why is the answer of Jayesh (Answer with +25 bounty) on the the question [AutoCompleteTextView doesn't show suggestions in Android 2.3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590384/autocompletetextview-doesnt-show-suggestions-in-android-2-3-5) displayed with a white transparent overlay (milky)? I have not seen this before on other answer or question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was downvoted and has a -3 score.

Answers with such a negative score are displayed differently to emphasize that the community thinks it is not helpful and should probably be ignored.

Comment: Ok thanks didn´t know that. Thought it was deleted or so.

Comment: @Jehof: You cannot see deleted answers until you have at least 10k reputation. They are displayed with a darker background.

Comment: Yes of course. I know that. By the way is the Feature @+username disabled on comments?

Comment: @Jehof: No, you don't need to name the author of a post in the comment, because they are always notified of comments anyway. Thus the name auto-complete doesn't include the author name.

Comment: @Jehof: See [How do comment @ replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Answer (score 1):

Because it has a -3 score.

Every answer with a score of -3 or worse (I think the limit is a -3), has an opacity like that.